# Service which monitors when apps are updated?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore, software-update, notifications

I have a couple of old applications which I adore, but really don't want to have on my iPhone at the moment, because they're terrible in iOS6 / iPhone 5 and haven't been updated  for over a year.  I'd like to get rid of it so it's not taking up space,  but would like to monitor its updates still.

Does such a service exist which 'monitors', or tracks the version of an application, and will let me know when it's updated?  This way, I could delete the app, wait for it to be updated, and re-install it again.

iTunes can kind of do this, in the sense that even if it's not installed on my iPhone it'll still let me know an update has been released.  I don't use iTunes, pretty much at all, so I don't want to use it that way.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of a service with the exact function. However lame this could sound, you could check out the app producer's website/fb/yt and sign-up for news or email newsletters which would inform you when these apps are updated.

Chances are slim, however, if the apps haven't been updated for more than a year.